# Writing an iterative self-referential SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complicated algorithm I need to implement in SQL, where the algorithm needs to be able to calculate a certain value for the first row, and on all subsequent rows needs to be able to use the previous row's calculated value as part of its own calculation. It's recursive, but starting from a position of the target column containing all NULLs.

I simplified my attempt to solve this with a cursor in the below:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null
    drop table #t;

-- create a simple demo table containing IDs 1 - 10 and an empty int column
with cte as (
    select x = 1

    union all

    select x = x + 1
    from cte
    where x < 10
)
select *, WriteVal = cast(null as int)
into #t
from cte



declare c cursor for
    select x from #t

declare @x int

open c

fetch next from c into @x

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    declare @WriteVal int

    -- Set @WriteVal to the previous row's [WriteVal] + 10. If previous row's [WriteVal] is NULL,
    -- (i.e. we're in the first row), use 0 + 10 instead.
    select @WriteVal = isnull(lag(WriteVal, 1) over (order by x), 0) + 10
    from #t
    where x = @x

    -- Update this row on the temp table with the value stored in @WriteVal
    update #t
    set WriteVal = @WriteVal
    where x = @x

    -- return the full table for debugging
    select *, [@WriteVal] = @WriteVal
    from #t

    fetch next from c into @x
end

close c
deallocate c
```

Starting dataset:

```
x   | WriteVal
----|---------
1   | NULL
2   | NULL
3   | NULL
4   | NULL
...
10  | NULL
```

What I'm expecting to see is:

1. on the first loop iteration, `lag(WriteVal, 1)` is NULL, so `@WriteVal` is set to 10, and then `10` is written to row 1's `[WriteVal]`
2. on the second loop iteration, `lag(WriteVal, 1)` is 10, so `@WriteVal` is set to (10 + 10) 20, and then `20` is written to row 2's `[WriteVal]`
3. on the third loop iteration, `lag(WriteVal, 1)` is 20, so `@WriteVal` is set to (20 + 10) 30, and then `30` is written to row 3's `[WriteVal]`
4. ... and so on ...

Expected result set:

```
x   | WriteVal
----|---------
1   | 10
2   | 20
3   | 30
4   | 40
...
10  | 100
```

What actually returns is every `[WriteVal]` set to `10`, and further inspection would indicate that subsequent loop iterations do not recognize the updated previous row's value, so `lag(WriteVal, 1)` always returns NULL. I assume some optimization or caching mechanism is to blame for this, or the updates aren't being truly committed until the query completes or something.

Actual result set:

```
x   | WriteVal
----|---------
1   | 10
2   | 10
3   | 10
4   | 10
...
10  | 10
```

How can I resolve this? Is there a better approach? I would rather avoid using cursors if possible, but the fact that it needs to be able to first calculate for row *n* and then use that result for row *n + 1* means I haven't had any luck with non-cursor based solutions using self-joins or window functions either

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish would really help.

Comment: If this is recursive, I doubt you need `LAG` here. Generally you get the "previous" value from the call back to the recursive CTE.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The actual dataset is enormous & very wide (even just considering the columns needed for the algorithm) and the actual algorithm is complicated and requires boatloads of context, so I've intentionally boiled it down to the root of the issue - or else this question would have been miles longer and the main actual problem would have been completely buried. Also, the question explains the desired results and explains what I am trying to accomplish. Given you managed to get your comment in within 15 seconds of me submitting, I'd appreciate if you took to the time to read it first.

Comment: Also, as it looks like `x` is unqieu in your data, then `LAG` is never going to return a value, as `where x = @x` is going to limit the dataset to a single row. Do you *really* have to use a `CURSOR` here though? SQL is a set based language, and a `CURSOR` is not a set based solution.

Comment: *"Given you managed to get your comment in within 15 seconds of me submitting the question"* In @GordonLinoff 's defence, they are very experienced in SQL; it's often quite easy for those of us that are to tell a question that does require sample data and expected results and I agree with their statement there (it didn't take me more than 15 seconds to come to that conclusion either). It doesn't have to be your full dataset though, that's why it's called a "sample". Just a small **representative** data set, along with the results you would expect for that data will greatly help us help you.

Comment: You're not providing the LAG function with a default value so it always returns NULL.  There are 2 optional parameters: Offset and Default.  You've provided the Offset (which is 1 by default anyway).

Comment: Why not just use `ROW_NUMBER`? `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) - 1) * 10)` Feels like you're overly complicating this with an rCTE and `CURSOR`.

Comment: To avoid loops in SQL Server have a look at the [Tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) based approach

Comment: Or just select (x-1)*10 from #tt?

Comment: @Kai Can you try changing `isnull(lag(WriteVal, 1) over (order by x) + 10, 0)` to `isnull(lag(WriteVal, 1) over (order by x), 0) + 10` I maybe wrong but you are adding the 10 to the isnull value before it it can change to 0 or be a value. If not, please let me know why.

Comment: Please understand I am not literally attempting to create a table with the values 10 thru 100 against IDs 1 thru 10 (I wouldn't be trying to write code for that, I'd just manually input the table). The question is my attempt to simplify the actual problem calculate *row n*, where *row n* relies on itself for *row n-1*, with as little noise as possible. The actual dataset is 20+ columns wide and the actual algorithm spec runs 2 pages long, hence why I didn't detail it here.

Comment: Could you please double check the expected output in your question? In its first version (before edit), I understood it was some kind of fibonacci sequence. Now it looks like you are trying to reinvent multiplication, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @YvesPédron sorry, yes, fixed the inconsistency now

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, you want:

```
select x,
       10 * row_number() over (order by x) as writeval
from #t;
```

To update the values, use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             10 * row_number() over (order by x) as new_writeval
      from #t t
     )
update toupdate
    set writeval = new_writeval;
```

Note that your query returned inconsistent results, because your cursor does not use an `order by`, so the results can change between invocations.